# Airflow AWS Connection

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, boto3

I've created an AWS connection using airflow where I've inserted AWS Key Access, AWS Secret Access Key and one extra arg "verify": false to disable ssl certificate. However, since I'm dealing with a **Requester Pays bucket** I'm not able to connect to the s3 bucket. I have tried to use also as an extra arg "RequestPayer":"requester" but without success. Does anyone know how to set this parameter on airflow? Thanks in advance

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwO4k.png)

I tried to use an extra arg "RequestPayer":"requester" on the AWS connection.